# AngularJS, Populating dependent Combobox

Tags: angularjs

What I am trying to achieve is to populate a child combobox with items which depend on a 'parent' combobox.

To clarify the problem, I have [created a Fiddle under this link](http://jsfiddle.net/qhaut/TsxTU/).

The combobox 'items' should populate every time the combobox 'group' has changed.

Controller:

```
function Controller( $scope ) {    
    var groups = [ ]; // ommitted for the sake of clarity
    
    $scope.groups = groups;                 // <- linked to cboGroup
    $scope.currentGroup = groups[0];        // <- should be updated from combobox
    $scope.currentItems = $scope.currentGroup.Items;  // <- linked to cboItems
    $scope.currentItem = $scope.currentItems[0];      // <- should be updated from cboItems
}
```

View

```
<select data-ng-model="currentGroup" data-ng-options="group.Name for group in groups"></select>
<select data-ng-model="currentItem" data-ng-options="item.Name for item in currentItems"></select>
```

I can't bring this to life declaratively. This should work without magic JavaScript - shouldn't it?

Thank you for your support

Comment: Codezilla's solution doesn't remove the empty item when the first pick list changes. Checkout my solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should refer **currentGroup** to populate the options inside **items** combobox:

```
<select data-ng-model="currentItem" data-ng-options="item.Name for item in currentGroup.Items"></select>
```

You don't need **$scope.currentItems** at all. So just update the last 2 lines inside the controller to:

```
$scope.currentItem = $scope.currentGroup.Items[0];
```

Now to remove the empty option, use super easy and light-weight **ng-change**:

```
<select data-ng-model="currentItem" data-ng-options="item.Name for item in currentGroup.Items" ng-change="groupChanged()"></select>
```

Define the corresponding change handler in the controller:

```
$scope.groupChanged = function(){
    $scope.currentItem = $scope.currentGroup.Items[0];
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't remove the empty item when the first pick list changes.

Comment: @SZA I did not deserve a downvote. The last 2 lines ($scope.currentItems = something and $scope.currentItem = something) in the asker's question are completely unnecessary. If you remove them you see that the empty option is visible for all the selections. And may be the asker prefers to keep them over $watch's performance implications.

Comment: @qhaut I have updated my answer to fix the empty option's issue.

Comment: Thank you CodeZilla and all. Works perfectly. Is there a possibilty to remove the empty option from the child's combobox? tx again!

Comment: @qhaut Please recheck my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a watcher to the controller like this. **You can also remove the empty item when you pick different value of the first drop down list.**

```
$scope.$watch('currentGroup', function () {
    $scope.currentItems = $scope.currentGroup.Items;
    $scope.currentItem = $scope.currentGroup.Items[0];
});
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TsxTU/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: That's a bad idea to add an expensive watcher when you can directly refer to `currentGroup.Items` (as pointed out by [Codezilla](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18082742/2057033)). In order to fill the current item with the first one of the list, you'd better simply use `ngChange` .

Comment: @Blackhole Your solution doesn't remove the empty item when the first ddl changes.

Comment: @zsong if will set item as selected then it wont work as have series od dependent select-box. setting first option as selected wont feed the values in next select box i feed them on ng-change . is there any way to keep some text by default selected always

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you're after:

http://jsfiddle.net/TsxTU/1/

How this works is its using the `select` as `label` for `item` in `group` syntax. So for the first select box, whatever the user selects will become the object bound to `currentGroup`. A similar thing is done for `currentItem`

We can then, optionally, use a `$watch` expression to be notified of that update and ensure that `currentItem` updates to the first item in the new group's `Items` array.

Answer (score 0):

There is other solution to this kind of issues. That is to broadcast.

Do broadcast after you got the data. In this example data came from Ajax call.

```
$http.get('/SampleProgram/get_all_users').success(function(rsList){
       $scope.users =  rsList;
       $scope.$broadcast('I got all the users');
    });
```

There should be listeners who always keeps their ears open for your broadcast message.

```
$scope.$on('I got all the users', function () {
        alert("Hey All the users are here already let's make another ajax call with those users");
    })
```